# Bundle install error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundle

This is the error message I got when I ran `bundle install`:

I'm running on Ubuntu 10.04, Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.0.1 and installed the latest RVM. My gemfile contains the sqlite3-ruby.

> /home/manju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

I got the same error message when I installed the package libsqlite3-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be sure to have the GNU compiling chain (GCC, make, ...)

On Ubuntu, all you have to do is be sure that the **build-essential** package is installed.

You can run `sudo apt-get install build-essential` for that.

The **libsqlite3-dev** package is probably also needed.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. I'm sorry I didn't see your message, otherwise I wouldn't have posted my answer!

Answer (score 0):

run

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
```

Then install sqlite3 gem

```
gem install sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

Just update your bundler, May be of any-one of the older gem is conflicting with latest one, this type of issues arises.

```
'gem install bundler'
```

and then `'bundler install'`

If you find again error, then delete GEM.lock file, then run `bundler install`. It may resolve the issue.